# Is the Cassandra Getting Started Instructions Broken?

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm trying to get started with Cassandra by following the directions on https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html, but step two doesn't make sense. This command: `docker run --name cassandra cassandra` starts a container. Then the second command (`docker run --rm -d --name cassandra --hostname cassandra --network cassandra cassandra`) attempts to start another container with the same name which fails because the container already exists. But if it didn't it refers to a network that doesn't exist.

If instead of the first command I run `docker network cassandra` and then run the second command as given the command in step four (`docker run --rm --network cassandra -v "$(pwd)/data.cql:/scripts/data.cql" -e CQLSH_HOST=cassandra -e CQLSH_PORT=9042 nuvo/docker-cqlsh`) fails to connect to cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the instructions on the Cassandra Quickstart page look to be out of date.  The following steps worked for me just now:

```
# step 1 (same as on the page)
docker pull cassandra:latest

# step 2, create network
docker network create cassandra

# step 2, start server
docker run --rm -d --name cassandra --hostname cassandra --network cassandra cassandra

# step 3, follow directions on page to create cql file

# step 4, run the contents of data.cql
docker run --rm -it --network cassandra  -v "$(pwd)/data.cql:/scripts/data.cql" nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh cassandra 9042 --cqlversion='3.4.5' -f /scripts/data.cql

# step 5, create interactive shell
docker run --rm -it --network cassandra  -v "$(pwd)/data.cql:/scripts/data.cql" nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh cassandra 9042 --cqlversion='3.4.5'
```

Comment: This also doesn't work following the current tutorial in the documentation quickstart page

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED]** I've removed my answer since we have now corrected the steps on the [Quickstart](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html) page on the Cassandra website ([CASSANDRA-17485](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17485)). Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Erick Seems the documentation for the quickstart page is still broken. It fails at step 4 when executing this command: `docker run --rm --network cassandra -v "$(pwd)/data.cql:/scripts/data.cql" -e CQLSH_HOST=cassandra -e CQLSH_PORT=9042 -e CQLVERSION=3.4.5 nuvo/docker-cqlsh`. I get this
``Can't establish connection, will retry again in 1 sconds
Can't establish connection, will retry again in 2 sconds
Failed to connect to cassandra at cassandra:9042
```
However  the log for the cassandra service says `Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...`